# High availability configuration for Kafka Connect Mongodb source connector

Tags: kubernetes, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, confluent-platform, mongodb-kafka-connector

I've been looking for specific information about high availability deployments of Kafka Connect connectors but found nothing.

In my case I have a Mongodb source connector deployed using the [Confluent Helm chart](https://github.com/confluentinc/cp-helm-charts/tree/master/charts/cp-kafka-connect). This chart supports setting the number of replicas.

Is setting `replicaCount` to a value >1 enough or there are other factors to consider (`tasks.max`, ...)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want highly available workers, then it's pod replicas, yes.

If you want distributed tasks across workers, that's `tasks.max`; if one worker dies, then tasks get rebalanced